# Create multiple layers from one table on GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver

I have a geometric SQL Server table with the following structure:

```
|--------|----------|---------|
|   id   |   geom   |  year   |
|--------|----------|---------|
```

I need to create 3 different layers in GeoServer from this table, filtering each by the `year` field, so that:

- Layer A: contains the points with year 2000
- Layer B: contains the points with year 2010
- Layer C: contains the points with year 2020

This could be an example:

```
|--------|----------|---------|
|   id   |   geom   |  year   |
|--------|----------|---------|
|   10   |   foo    |   2000  |  ---> Layer A
|--------|----------|---------|
|   11   |   foo    |   2010  |  ---> Layer B
|--------|----------|---------|
|   12   |   foo    |   2010  |  ---> Layer B
|--------|----------|---------|
|   13   |   foo    |   2020  |  ---> Layer C
|--------|----------|---------|
|   14   |   foo    |   2020  |  ---> Layer C
|--------|----------|---------|
```

Is it possible to do this directly in GeoServer without creating 3
views in the database and importing them as independent layers?

Comment: Yes, with SQL View https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a recent enough version of GeoServer, publish the layer three times, set a CQL filter in each to only return the features you desire:

https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/webadmin/layers.html#restricting-features-showing-up-in-the-layer

Will work transparently in both WMS and WFS.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to do this directly in GeoServer without creating 3 views in the database and importing them as independent layers?

Yes.

You can create three different WMS layers just by having three different styled layers, each symbolising, or not, by the year of interest.